# Can garbage collection take more than 1 minute?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Assuming I have a very large set of objects in a collection, for example 100 millions non-null objects in a `HashSet` or `Dictionary`, could it be that the garbage collection process take more than 1 or 2 minutes?

```
class GBObject
{
    String word;
    int Number;
    flaot FNumber;
    bool isTrue;
    decimal longNumber;
    GBOjbect innerObject;
    List<int> ints;
}
```

Is there how to measure the amount of time GC process took?

Comment: Both answers so far are just guesses. You do need to measure and see. In my experience though it would be EXTREMELY unusual for it to take that long.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess not if you have the default garbage collection settings.

Very large objects are allocation to the Large Object Heap which is not defragmented (by default) on garbage collection - defragmentation is what is likely to take up a lot of time.

To know for sure you will need to measure. See this code review stack exchange answer for some ways of doing so: [Measure GC Duration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/90210/260748)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.
GC Collection can require several minutes, even more, but since it's a task in the background your application won't slow down by much.

You neeed to understand how the collector works in the first place before actually start asking how much time it could take.
In short it frees the area of the memory which is no longer pointed by your program, and usually it starts after a considerable amount of memory is being occupied uselessly. Then the GC checks all the heaps used and if they're not pointed anymore it will basically delete them from memory thus freeing that space.

The total time depends on basically two things: number of objects and total memory occupied.
The first one tends to do take much more time the bigger the number, while the latter not always a big number of ram occupied means also a long time of collection.

You can always force the GC collection if you notice a lot of ram used when you actually don't point anymore to those objects with the following command:

```
GC.Collect();
```

For more info about the topic check [this arcticle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2006/november/clr-inside-out-investigating-memory-issues#S2)